# ant compiling error for junit testcase in other source folder with similar package structure

Tags: java, ant, junit, javac

```
    <target name="compile.src" depends="init" description="compile the source code " >
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/src">

            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

<path id="classpath.test">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${build}/src">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
    </fileset>
 </path>

<echo>${src.test} and tausif ${build}\test </echo>
<target name="compile.test" depends="compile.src" description="compile the test code " >
        <javac srcdir="${src.test}" destdir="${build}/test" debug="true" classpathref="classpath.test">
            <!--classpath refid="classpath.test" /-->
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
        </javac>
</target>
```

my structure for project is

```
project 
   > src 
      > example.samplePackage
   > test 
      > example.samplePackage
```

I am trying to compile first source folder in src and then trying to include all class files during compiling junit testcases in test source folder in similar package structure.
But it is showing me below Error.Please suggest something.

```
   [javac] C:\Project\test\examples\samplePackage\SampleTest.java:9: cannot find symbol
   [javac] symbol  : class Sample
   [javac] location: package examples.samplePackage
   [javac] import example.samplePackage.Sample;
                                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compile.test Ant target uses the compile.test classpath which is declared as:

```
<path id="classpath.test">
<fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
</fileset>
<fileset dir="${build}/src">
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
</fileset>
```

Is the "C:\Project\test\" folder amongst those?

Comment: no actually <path id="classpath.test"> i have given name only .. but C:\Project\test is not in it..only some jars like junit and other and class compiled from target compile.src i have included in fileset. My Sample.java file is in source folder 'src' while testcase is in source   folder 'test' within Project

Comment: Try changing the  srcdir="${src.test}" to  srcdir="${src}/**"

Comment: thanks , the above solution did not worked.I used pathelement instead of fileset for test class file to add in classpath , which worked.